# Issues with resetting a tic tac toe board- Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tic tac toe game in Python tkinter. Every time a button on the tic tac board is clicked, I'm adding either O or X to the list. The issue I'm having is when "X" or "O" wins and I call the reset function to reset the board. For some reason, after the board resets and I play again, a message box appears saying either "X" or "O" won, even though neither of them has won. Can someone please help me? My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.geometry("600x600+350+10")
turns = 0
pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
buttons_list = []
clicked = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]



def click(c, d):
    global turns
    turns += 1

    has_been_clicked = (buttons_list[c][d].cget("text") != " ")

    if has_been_clicked is True:
        return


    if turns % 2 == 0:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="X", fg="red", font=("Arial", 50))
        clicked[c * 3 + d] = "X"
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="O", fg="green", font=("Arial", 50))
        clicked[c * 3 + d] = "O"
    check()


def check():
    if (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[1] == "X" and clicked[2] == "X") or \
            (clicked[3] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[5] == "X") or \
            (clicked[6] == "X" and clicked[7] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X") or \
            (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X") or \
            (clicked[2] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[6] == "X") or \
            (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[3] == "X" and clicked[6] == "X") or \
            (clicked[1] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[7] == "X") or \
            (clicked[2] == "X" and clicked[5] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X"):
            messagebox.showinfo("X is the winner!")
            reset()
    elif (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[1] == "O" and clicked[2] == "O") or \
            (clicked[3] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[5] == "O") or \
            (clicked[6] == "O" and clicked[7] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O") or \
            (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O") or \
            (clicked[2] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[6] == "O") or \
            (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[3] == "O" and clicked[6] == "O") or \
            (clicked[1] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[7] == "O") or \
            (clicked[2] == "O" and clicked[5] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O"):
            messagebox.showinfo("O is the winner!")
            reset()


def reset():
    for b in buttons_list:
        for b2 in b:
            b2.configure(text=" ")

    for element in clicked:
        element = " "


for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        button = Button(screen, height=200, width=200, image=pixel, text=" ", compound="c", bg="papaya whip",
                        command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(i, j))
        button.grid(row=i, column=j)
        row.append(button)
    buttons_list.append(row)

screen.mainloop()
```

Thank you, joostblack for helping me solve the problem! Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.geometry("600x600+350+10")
turns = 0
pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
buttons_list = []
clicked = [" " for i in range(9)]



def click(c, d):
    global turns
    turns += 1

    has_been_clicked = (buttons_list[c][d].cget("text") != " ")

    if has_been_clicked is True:
        return


    if turns % 2 == 0:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="X", fg="red", font=("Arial", 50))
        clicked[c * 3 + d] = "X"
    else:
        buttons_list[c][d].configure(text="O", fg="green", font=("Arial", 50))
        clicked[c * 3 + d] = "O"
    check()


def check():
    if (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[1] == "X" and clicked[2] == "X") or \
            (clicked[3] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[5] == "X") or \
            (clicked[6] == "X" and clicked[7] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X") or \
            (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X") or \
            (clicked[2] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[6] == "X") or \
            (clicked[0] == "X" and clicked[3] == "X" and clicked[6] == "X") or \
            (clicked[1] == "X" and clicked[4] == "X" and clicked[7] == "X") or \
            (clicked[2] == "X" and clicked[5] == "X" and clicked[8] == "X"):
            messagebox.showinfo("X is the winner!")
            reset()
    elif (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[1] == "O" and clicked[2] == "O") or \
            (clicked[3] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[5] == "O") or \
            (clicked[6] == "O" and clicked[7] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O") or \
            (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O") or \
            (clicked[2] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[6] == "O") or \
            (clicked[0] == "O" and clicked[3] == "O" and clicked[6] == "O") or \
            (clicked[1] == "O" and clicked[4] == "O" and clicked[7] == "O") or \
            (clicked[2] == "O" and clicked[5] == "O" and clicked[8] == "O"):
            messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "O is the winner!")
            reset()
    elif clicked.count("X") + clicked.count("O") == 9:
        messagebox.showinfo("Tic Tac Toe", "The game ended in a draw!")
        reset()


def reset():
    for b in buttons_list:
        for b2 in b:
            b2.configure(text=" ")

    for i in range(len(clicked)):
        clicked[i] = " "


for i in range(3):
    row = []
    for j in range(3):
        button = Button(screen, height=200, width=200, image=pixel, text=" ", compound="c", bg="papaya whip",
                        command=lambda i=i, j=j: click(i, j))
        button.grid(row=i, column=j)
        row.append(button)
    buttons_list.append(row)

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really resetting `clicked`.

Change this:

```
for element in clicked:
    element = " "
```

to

```
for i in range(len(clicked)):
    clicked[i] = " "
```

Comment: I don't think you need to declare lists as global variables. It works for me without it.

Comment: @Roni My bad. I was thinking about my method.

Comment: Yeah there are many ways to create a list of empty strings. You can also do `[" " for i in range(9)]`

Comment: @joostblack, it should be `[" " for i in range(9+1)]`